Accessing client device connected to Android phone via Ethernet Tethering
I have an Android phone which I can share its internet connection via Ethernet tethering through an adapter (Ethernet to USB-C adapter). The device (camera) which is connected to the phone is able to utilise the internet connection successfully.
I want to access the device from my Android phone using its local IP address in the web browser of my Android phone since that device (camera) has a webapp running on it which allows accessing its features and configurations. However when I type in the local IP address (or the local host name) of the device in the browser it times out (the IP address is correct and I have double checked this multiple ways).

is this possible on Android?
how can I achieve this?
is this a DNS problem? (my Android "Private DNS Mode" is set to "Automatic" which is the default option.

I can achieve this using a laptop running windows without any issues but being able to use a mobile phone is a lot more convenient, as it means I won't have to carry a laptop with me.

How did you find out the IP address of the camera? First try ping with the IP address. Do not use the host name. Using the IP address and port (like https://192.168.10.100:80) should work fine in a web browser.

I tried IP address with port number but it still doesn't work.

How did you find the IP address of the camera? Can you ping the IP address.
